# Read multiple HDF5 files in Python using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to read a bunch of HDF5 files ("a bunch" meaning N > 1000 files) using `PyTables` and `multiprocessing`. Basically, I create a class to read and store my data in RAM; it works perfectly fine in a sequential mode and I'd like to parallelize it to gain some performance.

I tried a dummy approach for now, creating a new method `flatten()` to my class to parallelize file reading. The following example is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. `listf` is a list of strings containing the name of the files to read, `nx` and `ny` are the size of the array I want to read in the file:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import tables

class data:
    def __init__(self, listf, nx, ny, nproc=0):
        self.listinc = []
        for i in range(len(listf)):
             self.listinc.append((listf[i], nx, ny))

    def __del__(self):
        del self.listinc

    def get_dsets(self, tuple_inc):
        listf, nx, ny = tuple_inc
        x = np.zeros((nx, ny))
        f = tables.openFile(listf)
        x = np.transpose(f.root.x[:ny,:nx])
        f.close()
        return(x)

    def flatten(self):
        nproc = mp.cpu_count()*2

        def worker(tasks, results):
            for i, x in iter(tasks.get, 'STOP'):
                print i, x
                results.put(i, self.get_dsets(x))

        tasks   = mp.Queue()
        results = mp.Queue()
        manager = mp.Manager()
        lx      = manager.list()

        for i, out in enumerate(self.listinc):
            tasks.put((i, out))

        for i in range(nproc):
            mp.Process(target=worker, args=(tasks, results)).start()

        for i in range(len(self.listinc)):
            j, res = results.get()
            lx.append(res)

        for i in range(nproc):
            tasks.put('STOP')
```

I tried different things (including, like I did in this simple example, the use of a `manager` to retrieve the data) but I always get a `TypeError: an integer is required`.

I do not use ctypes array because I don't really require to have shared arrays (I just want to retrieve my data) and after retrieving the data, I want to play with it with NumPy.

Any thought, hint or help would be highly appreciated!

**Edit:** The complete error I get is the following:

```
Process Process-341:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/toto/test/rd_para.py", line 81, in worker
    results.put(i, self.get_dsets(x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 101, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: You might try simplifying a bit.  In particular, your entire "flatten" function could be replaced by a call to multiprocessing's map with "worker" as the function.  If you still get errors, a stack trace might be useful.

Comment: Perhaps overly simple, but have you tried printing the type of `i` in your `print i, x` line (unfortunately, you don't show us the output of the print statement)?

Comment: Also, reading up on the `iter` documentation, I can see another problem: `iter` stops if `tasks.get()` return value is equal to the sentinel (`'STOP'`), but your for loop shows that you expect `tasks.get()` to return 2 values (`i, x`), not a single string. So unless I misunderstand, `'STOP'` will never equal anything from `tasks.get()`, causing `iter` to proceed endlessly (and probably causing bad things in the end).

Comment: At least before it reaches the `'STOP'`, the print returns me what I expect (the integer `i`, and the list containing `listf[i]` (the string corresponding to the file to read) and the two integers `nx` and `ny`). I didn't thought of the problem you mentioned relative to `iter`; I will try to correct that as soon as possible! Thanks.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change the problem. Actually (I forgot to say it) I have one error per task. If I try to print what `results` give me it fails, so I guess the problem is due to the `results.put()`. By the way, I checked and `type(i)` is `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually very simple...

In the `worker`, since it is a tuple that I retrieve, i can't do:

```
result.put(i, self.get_dsets(x))
```

but instead I have to do:

```
result.put((i, self.get_dsets(x)))
```

which then works perfectly well.

Comment: Do you have some example code of actually using this in action?

Comment: Is it correct to get the results from the lx ListProxy? I've modified your code to return pandas dataframes, and use self.frames = lx at the very end of flatten.